# Naming requirements for TrackMetric?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm testing the collection of custom Metrics, using TrackMetric(), from my Windows console application. My metrics names were showing up in the Metrics Explorer, but it was showing "no data for...", or "Error retrieving data". I used names like "Metric: 0", "Metric: 1", etc.

Then I tried a different metric name without the colon AND IT WORKED!

```
var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
telemetry.TrackMetric("Test Metric: 1", 50); // <<< BAD with colon
telemetry.TrackMetric("Test Metric 1", 50); // <<< WORKS with spaces
telemetry.TrackMetric("TestMetric1", 50); // <<< WORKS
```

So, should I conclude that a colon ":" is not a legal character for a metric name?
Are there any other reserved (or bug-ridden) characters that I should know about?
Are there standard conventions or naming guidelines for Metric names?

Thanks

-John

Comment: It would also seem that if I include JUST the Metric named with a colon on a chart, I see "no data for...", but if I add another [valid] Metric I get a different error: "Error retrieving data".

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex used to sanitize the metric name:

```
private static readonly Regex InvalidNameCharacters = new Regex(@"[^0-9a-zA-Z-._()\/ ]", Property.SanitizeOptions);
```

[link to source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/4dd948ef9c4ca26ecfd6e76adf3e5af0f59d7bcf/src/Core/Managed/Shared/Extensibility/Implementation/Property.cs)